# How to click JavaScript Button WebBrowser Delphi

Tags: javascript, delphi, button, click, twebbrowser

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="javascript:start_form_submit('SUBMIT');">
      <imgsrc="graphics/proceed_confirm.gif" width="251" height="27" alt="Proceed to Confirmation" border="0">
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How to click in this button using delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a button, in the strictest sense of the word.  It is just an image inside of a clickable hyperlink.

In any case, neither HTML element has and `name` or `id` specified, so you have your work cut out for you.  You have to start by querying the `WebBrowser.Document` for the `IHTMLDocument2` interface and then dig through the browser's DOM interfaces as needed looking for the `<a>` element you are interested in, then you can call its `click()` method.

Answer (score 1):

thanks bro, im using

function

```
procedure ExecuteScript(doc: IHTMLDocument2; script: string; language: string);
begin
  if doc <> nil then
  begin
    if doc.parentWindow <> nil then
      doc.parentWindow.ExecScript(script, Olevariant(language)) ;
  end;
end;
```

and using on button1

```
script := 'javascript:start_form_submit("SUBMIT");';
ExecuteScript(webbrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2, script, 'javascript');
```